# Replace switch case (in c++) with literal object like in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

In javascript & in many other programming languages there is `switch case`.

```
switch(n)
{
case 1:
  alert(1);
  break;
case 2:
  alert(2);
  break;
default:
  alert(3);
}
```

Javascript also allows you to shorten this up alot.

```
alert({1:1,2:2}[n]||3); // literal obj , i need this.

alert([1,2][n-1]||3); // array
```

**Is there something similar in c++ ?**

literal objects...

more advanced example

```
var 
moveUp=function(){},
moveDown=function(){},
doNothing=function(){};

switch(txt)
{
case 'moveUp':
  moveUp();
  break;
case 'moveDown':
  moveDown();
  break;
default:
  doNothing();
}
```

I prefer:

```
window.moveUp=function(){}
window.moveDown=function(){}
window.doNothing=function(){}

window[txt]?window[txt]():window.doNothing();
```

or just

```
window.moveUp=function(){}
window.moveDown=function(){}

!window[txt]||window[txt]();
```

`window` can be a any other (custom or predefined) object.

Comment: Acctually, this example of yours can be shortened to `alert(n)`. :)

Comment: it's an example... want that i change the numbers? look at the advancedd example ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map` works well for that. You can create it using brace notation:

```
std::map<int, int> m = { {1,1}, {2,2}, {3, 3} };
```

Which makes it easy to use later:

```
f((std::map<int, int>{ {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3} })[1]);
```

However, depending on your needs to handle missing keys, you might want to write some helpers for that.

To get closer to what you had in your 2nd example:

```
void f ();
void g ();

f((std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)> { {"a", f}, {"b", g} })["a"]);
```

Frankly, though, if I were you, I would stop writing JS in C++. They are two different languages with different practices and idioms. Shoehorning "clever" JS oneliners into C++ syntax isn't a very good idea.

Comment: works also with strings? i need literal objects... not the js brackets {} not []

Comment: @cocco yep. And functions.

Comment: mind if you show a simple example fith literal obj and functions? i'm very new to c++

Comment: @cocco I am at a loss of words.

Comment: what do you mean? ... i'm new to c++ looks alot of code switch case is prolly better solution ?

Comment: right... thats not really relative to my question... understandeing the answer now... the code is alot more complex vs the js solution... in js switch case is wors than arrays or objects... in c++ apparently no..

Comment: @cocco This code is fast, not extremely fast, more like very moderately fast to rather fast. It takes some space, not a lot but a bit.

Comment: i'm using javascript objects to send data over websockets to a microcontroller. literal objecdts would be "easy" to use...

Comment: @cocco See and now we're hitting the wall of you not telling upfront what you want to do in the first place.You should read up about the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: nono... the question is answered correctly by your code... those are just some other extra questions is addedd.. everything is ok... std::map

Comment: Ad N uses insert & make_pair?

Comment: since i'm lazy and adding insert & make_pair has no advangages in my case this is prolly the best answer... thx

Answer (score 1):

Not very familiar with JS, but first of all let me warn that C++ is loved, but not for its brevity nor for its friendly syntax ;)

My guess is you could try to achieve something similar to what you want using a map from you key to a callable. (If I understood `txt` is your key)

```
void functionFoo()
{ /* ... */ }
void functionBoo()
{ /* ... */ }

std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> callableMap;
callableMap.insert(std::make_pair("first key", &functionFoo);
callableMap.insert(std::make_pair("second key", &functionBoo);
...
std::string key = "first key";
callableMap[key](); // invoke functionFoo
```

Of course, you are not limited to callable that take no argument and return no value. This is your callable type: `std::function<void()>`, and you can make it as complicated as you want.

Comment: is this fast? does it take more program space? i need c++ to program microcontrollers.

Comment: Not sure how you quantify *fast*; but it is definitely faster than the equivalent JS ;)

Actually, you would have a hard time making it faster than a plain switch statement, which is usually implemented as a very efficient jump-table. But here, you gain the ability to use non-integral type keys (if that is anything you want), and to get a syntax closer to what you asked for.

Comment: @cocco Switch will probably be the fastest runtime. But you will be limited to integral type keys (i.e., no `string` as keys). Also, your question did not really seem focused on runtime performance, but more on syntax.

Comment: why do you use insert & make_pair and Bartek Banachewicz doesn't?

Comment: @AdN Probably `string` keys shouldn't be used here anyway.

Comment: I'd also suggest using C++11 `unordered_map` which has O(1) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

For contiguous values, you can write similar code in C++:

```
void print(int n)
{
    // Check that 0 <= n < 3.

    using T = int[3];
    std::cout << T{4, 9, 18}[n] << std::endl;
}
```

For arbitrary values, you could use a `std::map` as other answers suggest, though the corresponding construction would probably be a static version of that container (which doesn't exist in the standard library).

Comment: As i'm new to c++ the above is a little unclear... can you explain a little more?

Comment: your not using map, cout is?

Comment: ok ... now i understand the code... my example js is all about literal objects